# Deploying to iOS 3.1.3 device with Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

How do I deploy to a iOS 3.1.3 device with Xcode 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Follow the steps in Ignacio's answer to install debugging support for iOS 3.x. (I think this is optional.)
2. Go to the project (not the target) `Info` tab. Change the `iOS Deployment Target` to `3.1` or earlier.
3. Go to the project (not the target) `Build Settings` tab. Change the `Architectures` to `armv6`. (Click on `armv7` -> Press `Other` -> Press `+` -> Enter `armv6` -> Press `Done`.
4. Go to `Info.plist`. Change the `Required device capabilities`' item 0 to `armv6`.

Answer (score 2):

You set the Build Target to OS 3.0

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xcode 4.2 (I don't remember the exact version on which support for iOS 3 was made on demand) you need to go to

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads
```

and install support for the devices you require (3.0 - 3.2.2 and 4.0 - 4.1 show up on mine).

After you have done that just select your deployment target to 3.1.3 (or below) and you're good to go.